# How to ask user input in XLISP?

Tags: lisp

I am writing a program in XLISP which requires me to ask user input. I have used C language and it was fairly simple in it bt I'm new to LISP and particularly XLISP, which makes a bit difficult to search for the right thing for it. The thing I want to write in XLISP is like this:

```
scanf("Enter your position: %d %d\n",pos1,pos2);
```

How do I write this in XLISP?

Comment: Use a manual. For example: http://www.mcs.sdsmt.edu/csc461/Resources/Lisp/XLispManual.pdf
Page 30, FORMAT.

Comment: Your example is wrong.  I think you mean:
    printf("Enter your position: ");
    scanf("%d %d\n,&pos1,&pos2);

Comment: Any example where `scanf` is being applied to user input, particularly interactive user input, is wrong.

Comment: [XLISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLISP) is not one language, but a family of different languages linked only because they have a common author and name. The latest XLisp is based on the Scheme language, whereas a previous one was geared toward similarity to Common Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic would be a function `enter-position` with a program block (a list of instructions), e.g. [progn](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm):

```
(defun enter-position ()
(progn
    (format t "Enter your position:")
    (let pos1 (read))
    (let pos2 (read))))
```

(The inputs might need to be sanitized by auxiliary functions, but that's another part of the story)
The two variables pos1 and pos2 would then have "lexical scope", so they would not be visible outside the scope of `enter-position`.